# C++ Tic Tac Toe Game: My code is doubling my outcome from my loop. What is wrong?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <ctime>
#include "Console.h"
using namespace System;
using namespace std;

int main()
{

// Console::SetCursorPosition(10,10 );

const int Rows = 3, Cols = 3;
char gameBoard[Rows][Cols]{
};

do
{

    Console::Clear();


    for (size_t row = 0; row < Rows; row++)
    {
        Console::SetCursorPosition(30, 10 + row);
        for (size_t col = 0; col < Cols; col++)
        {
            cout << "|" << gameBoard[row][col];
        }
        cout << '|';
        cout << "\n";


    }
    int rowInput;
    int colInput;
    Console::SetCursorPosition(28, 15);
    cout << "Row (0 -> 2): ";
    cin >> rowInput;

    if (cin.fail() == true)
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
    }

    else if (rowInput <= 0 || rowInput >= 3)
        break;

    Console::SetCursorPosition(28, 16);
    cout << "Col (0 -> 2): ";
    cin >> colInput;
    do
    {
        if (gameBoard[rowInput][colInput] == 'X' || gameBoard[rowInput][colInput] == 'O'){
            cout << "That is already taken";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');

        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    } while (true);
    gameBoard[rowInput][colInput] = 'X';
//      system("pause");
//  return 0;
    cout << "\n";
} while (true);



system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

The code that is outputting twice is :

```
do
    {
        if (gameBoard[rowInput][colInput] == 'X' || gameBoard[rowInput][colInput] == 'O'){
            cout << "That is already taken";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');

        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    } while (true);
```

This is part of my Tic Tac Toe game, but I am not sure why it prints out "This is already taken" twice. Any help is appreciated. Also another tip I am looking to receive if anyone can show me is how to make the game pick a random spot for the AI to choose.

Comment: This infinite loop is the least of your problems your code has several issues (e.g., `if (rowInput <= 0 || rowInput >= 3)` is wrong). My advice is review your code thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the code through here quite easily. Singlestepping through windows debug should do the trick.

1. So, we enter our row and column values. Because you don't do `cin.ignore` after doing `cin >> colInput` there's still a `\n` on the input stream.
2. We check if that part of the board is already filled. Lets assume it is.
3. We output our message (without a newline at the end, I note)
4. We clear `cin` by ignoring everything up until the last `\n`. `cin` is now empty.
5. We reach `while (true)`
6. We check to see if that part of the board is already filled. It still is! We haven't changed our location yet!
7. We output our message (without a newline at the end, I note)
8. We clear `cin` by ignoring everything up until the last `\n`. Because `cin` is empty, this causes the program to wait until enter is returned.

As you can see, you've got yourself stuck in an infinite loop. That `do...while` loop needs to be rethought.

```
do
{
/* 2 and 6 */  if (gameBoard[rowInput][colInput] == 'X' || gameBoard[rowInput][colInput] == 'O'){
/* 3 and 7 */    cout << "That is already taken";
/* 4 and 8 */    cin.clear();
                 cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');

               }
               else {
                 break;
               }
/* 5      */ } while (true);
```

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to get it to work, but still cant figure it out. Sorry, not the most knowledgeable. Also I forgot to add, that once it types That is already taken, im trying to get it to go back to the question where it asks for Row and Col.

Comment: @user3623692 your question was 'why does this print twice', and now you know ;) General issues of rewriting code are beyond the scope of stack overflow. Do you have any _specific_ questions?

Comment: Well the question would be "How do I get it to go loop back to the question where it asks Rows and Cols? I tried surrounding it all with a do while but that didnt work either.

Comment: @user3623692 the problem is that the code is fragile and very unfinished. There are still more bugs... for example, you ask for rows and columns in 0-2, but you consider a value of <= 0 to be an error and end the game. Rewriting this game for you is slightly out of the scope of an SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop has several problems, the code:

```
    do
    {
        if (gameBoard[rowInput][colInput] == 'X' || gameBoard[rowInput][colInput] == 'O'){
            cout << "That is already taken";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');

        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    } while (true);
```

is equivalent to:

```
while (gameBoard[rowInput][colInput] == 'X' || gameBoard[rowInput][colInput] == 'O'){
    cout << "That is already taken";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
};
```

and if you pay attention, the condition `gameBoard[rowInput][colInput] == 'X' || gameBoard[rowInput][colInput] == 'O'` don't change its status, due to the variables `rowInput` and `colInput` are never modified inside the loop.

By the way, I think you don't need that loop at all. Just the code inside:

```
if (gameBoard[rowInput][colInput] == 'X' || gameBoard[rowInput][colInput] == 'O'){
            cout << "That is already taken";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
}
```